# How to check if a character is contained in string?

Tags: scala

I want to check if the string contains the character. I am writing a hangman code.
For example, here is the word to guess: `"scala"`, but it looks like `"_ _ _ _ _"` tho the user. Let's assume that user inputs letter `'a'`, then it must look like `"_ _ a _ a"`.

```
def checkGuess(){
if (result.contains(user_input)) {
    val comp = result.toCharArray
    for (i <- comp){
        if (user_input != comp(i))
            comp(i) = '_'
        comp(i)
        }
    val str = comp.toString
    }
}
```

Is this right?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think this is homework, so I'll probably regret answering if it is...

```
case class HangmanGame(goal: String, guesses: Set[Char] = Set.empty[Char]) {
  override def toString = goal map {c => if (guesses contains c) c else '_'} mkString " "
  val isComplete = goal forall { guesses.contains } 
  def withGuess(c: Char) = copy(guesses = guesses + c)
}
```

Then

```
val h = HangmanGame("scala")
h: HangmanGame = _ _ _ _ _

scala> val h1 = h.withGuess('a')
h1: HangmanGame = _ _ a _ a

scala> val h2 = h1.withGuess('l')
h2: HangmanGame = _ _ a l a

scala> val h3 = h2.withGuess('s')
h3: HangmanGame = s _ a l a

scala> val h4 = h3.withGuess('c')
h4: HangmanGame = s c a l a

scala> h4.isComplete
res5: Boolean = true
```

**UPDATE**

Okay, so it does look like homework.  I guess the genie's out of the bottle now, but unless you get up to speed on Scala very quickly you're going to have a really hard time explaining how it works.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
scala> def checkGuess(str: String, c: Char) = str.replaceAll("[^"+c+"]","_")
checkGuess: (str: String,c: Char)java.lang.String

scala> checkGuess("scala",'a')
res1: java.lang.String = __a_a

scala> def checkGuess2(str: String, C: Char) = str map { case C => C; case _ => '_'}
checkGuess2: (str: String,C: Char)String

scala> checkGuess2("scala",'a')
res2: String = __a_a
```

Comment: How about when the user input type is string? In other words, CheckGuess(str1: String, str2: String )

Comment: +1 for version 2, although you should probably take a set of chars. @Sam: That is preprocessing easily done, e.g. `str2(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some comments about how you wrote this. When using this syntax, `def checkGuess() { ... }`, the function will not return any value, it will return Unit instead.

This means that you're using it for its side effect only (such as setting some var outside the code block or printing some values). The issue is that you are not setting any value or printing anything inside the function (no printing, no assignment).

What you don't show in your code snippet is where you store the string to guess, the user input and the feedback to print. You can pass the first two as arguments and the last one as a returned value. This make the input and output self contained in the function and does not presume where you render the feedback.

```
def feedback(target:String, guesses:String): String = { 
  // target is the string to guess like "scala"
  // guesses are the letters that have been provided so far, like "ac"
  // last expression should be the feedback to print for instance "_ca_a"
}
```

Then you can think about the function as transforming each letter in `target` with _ or with itself depending on whether it is contained in `guesses`. For this the `target map { c => expr }` would work pretty well if you figure out how to make *expr* return *c* if c is in `guesses` and '_' otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Staying as close as possible to the main question ( *How to check if a character is contained in string?* ) what I did was changing the approach, i.e.:

Inside a **for** loop, I wanted to do something like `some_chr == 't'` 
and I did the following `some_chr.toString == "t"` and it worked just fine.